# Libgit2sharp Iterate commits from newest to oldest

Tags: c#, linq, libgit2sharp

I want to iterate through all changesets of a repository. I want to avoid to first read all commits in the ram and then iterate through then

Currently, I've got this method

```
   foreach (LibGit2Sharp.Commit commit in repo.Commits)
   {
        return Transform(commit);
   }
```

I know that I could do this:

```
foreach (LibGit2Sharp.Commit commit in repo.Commits.OrderByDescending(i=>i.Committer.When))
```

but then it reads all commits and then linq reorders them afterward.

Isn't there any way to let libgit2sharp iterate in a reversed order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a commit `Filter` and use it to sort the commits by:

- `Reverse`
- `Time`
- `Topological`

#### Example:

```
var repo = new LibGit2Sharp.Repository("/Users/sushi/code/sushi/Xamarin.PlayScript.Starling");
var filter = new CommitFilter()
{
    SortBy = CommitSortStrategies.Reverse 
};
IEnumerable<Commit> commits = repo.Commits.QueryBy(filter);
foreach (var commit in commits)
{
    Console.WriteLine(commit.Committer.When);
}
```